# Use EMV-enabled Credit Card (chip card) for Windows Smart Card log-in?

Tags: windows, security, login, windows-10, smartcard

I have a USB Smart Card Reader and a Credit Card with Smart Chip (EMV) on it. So I was wondering if I can associate this card to my Windows Administrator profile (local user account) and use it as a second layer of protection for my log-in? If yes, how can I do this? I'm using Windows 10.

**More details:**

Reader: GemPC Twin, HWP108760 C

Card: Gemalto MGY - U1090942C 11/14 ICA-1065

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/446969/how-to-logon-to-windows-with-a-smartcard

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there no way to use a standard EMV card with windows.You must use a card that is specifically designed for smartcard logon and supports PKI and the correct CSP etc. The cheapest available card is the ACOS5 smartcard.
[Available Here](https://www.smartcardfocus.com/shop/ilp/id%7E670/acos5-64-evaluation-kit/p/index.shtml)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).