# Is it possible to require a TOTP on Windows Login using existing or custom software?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, login, google-authenticator

I have always been looking for a way to require a Two-Factor Authentication (One Time) Passcode on my Windows Login. Using an algorithm such as [TOTP,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) this should be easy, and require no internet connection, and it could work with something like [Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) to require a 6-digit code generated by my mobile device as I log into my computer. I have been snooping around, and I haven't found any program that can do this, therefore I've come to the conclusion that this is near impossible, and I am looking for validation of that observation.

To be clear, I haven't found *any* software that can do this, and I'm not looking for a comparison of different products as a recommendation, since that's not what SO is about. I'm simply asking if it is possible, and if so, if there is *any* software that does it already, or if it is something I'd have to create myself.

Comment: Windows version and account type may be a factor here - you've mentioned windows 10, but is this a local or 'microsoft account' account?

Comment: I'm open to a solution for either of the account types. My personal account is technically a microsoft account, but I wouldn't be adverse to changing it for the additional security this provides. Also, I would strongly like to avoid, but am not totally against, doing this in an Active Directory setting.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but if your computer has a smartcard slot you could possibly use something from http://superuser.com/questions/446969/how-to-logon-to-windows-with-a-smartcard

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have committed to supporting U2F FIDO2 in a update to Windows 10 for Active Directory authentication. ([source](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2018/04/17/password-less-sign-in-to-windows-10-azure-ad-using-fido2-is-coming-soon-plus-other-cool-news/))

Comment: Source is dead at link

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Active Directory currently supports smartcard authentication as a second factor of authentication. This is designed to support the US Department of Defense "Common Access Card".

Some "security dongle" products support the emulation of a Smartcard and thus can be used with Active Directory today (Microsoft are moving towards FIDO2/WebAuthn but that isn't yet available for on-premises Active Directory). As one example, see this extensive deployment guide from [YubiKey](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006456-yubikey-smart-card-deployment-guide).

Answer (score 0):

I found this one: http://www.rohos.com/rohos-logon-key/, but did not have a chance to try it yet.

Comment: I have tried it. It works and answers OP's question.